# Cast Linear layout with ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have linear layout in `xml` file:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/ben_pay_methods"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/layout1">
 </LinearLayout>
```

I am using it like this:

```
listView = (ListView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.ben_pay_methods);
```

Application is running fine. The problem is when I am trying to build the signed apk, it's giving me error:

**Unexpected cast to ListView: layout tag was linear layout [WrongViewCast]**

How can I resolve this problem without changing the xml?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you even type casting `LinearLayout` to `ListView`? If your code is working then its very strange. In no world its a right way to do it.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : I have tested the app. It's working. I am getting error on generating the signed apk

Comment: How in the world is this running fine? That should be a major problem regardless of whether you are signing it or not.

Comment: Are you using "R.id.ben_pay_methods" id  two times I project one for Listview and second for LinerLayout??

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Yes. exactly.

Comment: @RonakPatel: ok that's why problem is occur during building signed apk. Because when we build apk lint checker is run and mark duplicate ids as error in newer ADT version.to fix issue either disable lint checker or use different id's for both views in xml

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : ohh.. Thanks. that was the problem.